# GROUP BY with specific column name SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, scripting

Example i having a table name DEPARTMENT

```
//DEPARTMENT
D#
--------
1
2
3
```

Now having a project table

```
//Project
P#      D#
-----------
1       1
2       1
3       2
4       1
```

So how should i use the group by with specific column name when display out all the information using prompt, it should be something like

```
Enter Department Number : 1

D#      total project
---------------------
1            3
```

So far i done like this

```
ACCEPT dno PROMPT 'Enter Department Number: ' 
SELECT DNAME FROM DEPARTMENT WHERE D#=&dno;
SELECT count(*) from PROJECT where D#=&dno;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
select DNAME, count(Project) AS "total project" FROM DEPARTMENT d, PROJECT p
WHERE d.dno=p.dno and D.DNO=&dno  group by DNAME;
```

to get total only

```
select  count(Project) AS "total project" FROM DEPARTMENT d, PROJECT p
WHERE d.dno=p.dno and D.DNO=&dno  group by DNAME;
```

Comment: but i want to print the specific total project column . isnt possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try JOIN between two tables,

```
ACCEPT dno PROMPT 'Enter Department Number: ' 
SELECT DNAME, count(*)
    FROM DEPARTMENT d, PROJECT p
    WHERE d.dno=p.dno and d.dno=&dno
    group by d.DNAME;
```

**EDIT**

Displaying `dno` and `DNAME` along with count of projects

```
ACCEPT dno PROMPT 'Enter Department Number: ' 
SELECT d.dno,DNAME, count(*) as 'total'
    FROM DEPARTMENT d, PROJECT p
    WHERE d.dno=p.dno and d.dno=&dno
    group by d.dno,DNAME;
```

Comment: but i want to print the specific total project column . isnt possible?

Comment: count(*) will do that for you.

Comment: Here in this query, it will count projects `group by DNAME`